# Elasticsearch match prefix, no matches found

Tags: elasticsearch

Following an elastic search tutorial on some basic queries:

```
#Create the index with no mapping
curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/

#add some data
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/ -d '{"title":"river dog"}'
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/ -d '{"title":"data"}'
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/ -d '{"title":"drive"}'
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/ -d '{"title":"dzone"}'

#try to perform a "starts-with" style query...
curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty -d '{
        "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
           "title": {
             "query": "d",
             "max_expansions": 5
           }
         }
       }
     }' | grep title
```

but I am receiving the message `no matches found: 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty`. If I visit `http://127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search` or curl it, the results are there. What am I missing?

Comment: It [worked](http://pastebin.com/wQzAmu2X) for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a shell problem.

`zsh` uses `?` for wild card matching, so you'll have to quote it to use in a literal string.

For example;

```
> echo ?
zsh: no matches found: ?

> echo 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty
zsh: no matches found: 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty
```

To fix it in `zsh`, either quote the string;

```
> echo "127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty"
127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty
```

...or escape the question mark with a backslash;

```
> echo 127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search\?pretty
127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked:

```
curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty' -d
```

I needed quotes around the URL.

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0) libcurl/7.35.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

I've run the command in 2 different emulators.  Quotes are required around the URL but I'm not really sure why. Bonus points for anyone who can tell me, as it doesn't appear to be required for the flag.

I am using `zsh`, not bash.

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot..some terminals have issues with the `?` (I think it can stand for a wildcard) in URLs.

Comment: did you mean "'" @Sam

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure sometimes terminals balk at `?` in URLs when I use cURL.  I've fixed it by putting quotes around it (like you did), so it knows it is an entire string.

Comment: Which shell are you using? (echo $SHELL)

Comment: echo $SHELL => `/bin/zsh`

Comment: That was it. I ran `chsh` changing shell back to `bash`. Good call. Submit your answer

Answer (score 1):

On zsh put the url in quotes:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/userindex1?pretty"
```